# Empty assignment (model theory)

Tags: logic, model-theory

Reading through “logic of mathematics” (page 42) I came across the following example:

$$\mathbb{A}\models \forall x(x\le x)[\emptyset] \text{ iff for each } a\in A, \mathbb{A}\models (x\le x) [\emptyset (a/x)] \text{ iff for each } a\in A, x[a/x] \le^A x[a/x]$$

I’m not understanding the second “iff”, in particular how did the empty assignment disappear? I was thinking it ought to be something like $\text{ iff for each } a\in A, x[\emptyset(a/x)] \le^A x[\emptyset(a/x)]$ and I’m basing this off the definition given on page 40 which says that for atomic formulas you have the following:
$$\mathbb{A}\models r(t_1,\ldots, t_n)[p] \text{ iff } 
r^A(t_1[p],\ldots, t_n[p])$$
where is an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignments $[\emptyset(a/x)]$ and $[a/x]$ are the same thing: adding $\emptyset$ to $a/x$ doesn't result in anything different. Remember that a (incomplete) variable assignment for a formula $\varphi$ is a (partial) map from the free variables of $\varphi$ to elements of the structure. Concatenation (a la "$\emptyset(a/x)$") then corresponds to taking the union of the indicated functions. For example, "$t[(a/x)(b/y)]$" means "take the term $t$, replace each free $x$ by $a$, and replace each free $y$ by $b$," and we have $$t[(a/x)(b/y)]=(t[a/x])[b/y]=(t[b/y])[a/x]$$ (we can do the replacements all at once, or first $x$ then $y$, or first $y$ then $x$).

Now what about "$t[\emptyset(a/x)]$" (for $t$ some term)? Well, just remember that $\emptyset\cup A=A$ for all $A$. The expression "$t[\emptyset(a/x)]$" means, intuitively, "Take $t$, do all the substitutions that $\emptyset$ tells you to do, and also replace every free $x$ by $a$." Since $\emptyset$ is, well, empty, it doesn't tell you to do any substitutions, so you're just looking at replacing every free $x$ by $a$ - that is, $t[a/x]$.

Comment: Thanks, but I’m not really understanding your answer. I’m very new to this content; also I thought an assignment was a map from the Terms to $A$?. Could you possibly add more details to your answer.... I’m very new to this chapter (and I spent about 1.5 months answering all the questions in the previous 4 chapters on Boolean algebras)

Comment: @Squirtle Sorry, I got my definition of assignment swapped around: an assignment sends free variables to elements of $A$. (It then *extends to* a map from terms in the appropriate variables to elements of $A$, but it *starts out* as just a map on the variables.)

Comment: I'm not sure what additional details you're looking for. What do you think "$t[\emptyset(a/x)]$" means, for $t$ a term? The point is that when we concatenate assignments we're essentially taking a union, and $\emptyset$ vanishes when we do that.

Comment: I thought it meant $t[\emptyset]$ - since the image of the empty function is the emptyset - but what that means is unclear to me, and in particular it seems the “a/x” would be lost.

Comment: @Squirtle I think I see the issue: you're reading "$\emptyset(a/x)$" as $\emptyset$ applied to $(a/x)$ in some sense, is that right? If so, that's incorrect. To be fair, this is a bit annoying notation - maybe it would be better written as "$t[\emptyset, (a/x)]$." Does that help?

Comment: @Squirtle Did my previous comment/edit clarify things? If not, what remains unclear?

Comment: I was hospitalized for awhile shortly after your responses... hence the lack of a response.  But to your question directly, I do not follow it... but I have my own response.  $\emptyset$ is an assignment. And $p(a|x)(y) = p(y)$ if $y\neq x$ and equals $a$ if $y=x$; and $\text{Dom}[p(a|x)] = \text{Dom}[p] \cup \{x\}$.  So in this case   $\emptyset:\emptyset\to A$ so that Dom$[\emptyset(a|x)] = \emptyset\cup\{x\}=\{x\}$. Then necessarily $\emptyset(a|x)(y) =\emptyset(a|x)(x) = a$.  But this is the same thing as substituting $x$ for $a$.  Is my explanation correct? Thank you.